# noVNC Console not working on Charmed Openstack

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, novnc

I just deployed charmed openstack based on the latest guide from the [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-overview.html), but I cannot connect the noVNC console.

```
$ juju status
Model      Controller       Cloud/Region      Version  SLA          Timestamp
openstack  maas-controller  maas-one/default  2.9.32   unsupported  10:34:25-05:00

App                       Version  Status  Scale  Charm                   Channel        Rev  Exposed  Message
ceph-mon                  17.2.0   active      3  ceph-mon                quincy/stable  109  no       Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-osd                  17.2.0   active      3  ceph-osd                quincy/stable  534  no       Unit is ready (3 OSD)
ceph-radosgw              17.2.0   active      1  ceph-radosgw            quincy/stable  526  no       Unit is ready
cinder                    20.0.0   active      1  cinder                  yoga/stable    557  no       Unit is ready
cinder-ceph               20.0.0   active      1  cinder-ceph             yoga/stable    502  no       Unit is ready
cinder-mysql-router       8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
dashboard-mysql-router    8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
glance                    24.0.0   active      1  glance                  yoga/stable    544  no       Unit is ready
glance-mysql-router       8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
keystone                  21.0.0   active      1  keystone                yoga/stable    572  no       Application Ready
keystone-mysql-router     8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
mysql-innodb-cluster      8.0.29   active      3  mysql-innodb-cluster    8.0/stable      26  no       Unit is ready: Mode: R/O, Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.
ncc-mysql-router          8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
neutron-api               20.1.0   active      1  neutron-api             yoga/stable    526  no       Unit is ready
neutron-api-mysql-router  8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
neutron-api-plugin-ovn    20.1.0   active      1  neutron-api-plugin-ovn  yoga/stable     29  no       Unit is ready
nova-cloud-controller     25.0.0   active      1  nova-cloud-controller   yoga/stable    601  no       Unit is ready
nova-compute              25.0.0   active      3  nova-compute            yoga/stable    594  no       Unit is ready
openstack-dashboard       22.1.0   active      1  openstack-dashboard     yoga/stable    546  no       Unit is ready
ovn-central               22.03.0  active      3  ovn-central             22.03/stable    31  no       Unit is ready
ovn-chassis               22.03.0  active      3  ovn-chassis             22.03/stable    46  no       Unit is ready
placement                 7.0.0    active      1  placement               yoga/stable     49  no       Unit is ready
placement-mysql-router    8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server           3.9.13   active      1  rabbitmq-server         3.9/stable     149  no       Unit is ready
vault                     1.7.9    active      1  vault                   1.7/stable      68  no       Unit is ready (active: true, mlock: disabled)
vault-mysql-router        8.0.29   active      1  mysql-router            8.0/stable      30  no       Unit is ready

Unit                           Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports               Message
ceph-mon/0                     active    idle   0/lxd/5  10.113.1.63                         Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/1                     active    idle   1/lxd/4  10.113.1.64                         Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/2*                    active    idle   2/lxd/5  10.113.1.65                         Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-osd/0*                    active    idle   0        10.113.1.32                         Unit is ready (3 OSD)
ceph-osd/1                     active    idle   1        10.113.1.30                         Unit is ready (3 OSD)
ceph-osd/2                     active    idle   2        10.113.1.31                         Unit is ready (3 OSD)
ceph-radosgw/0*                active    idle   0/lxd/6  10.113.1.67     80/tcp              Unit is ready
cinder/0*                      active    idle   1/lxd/5  10.113.1.66     8776/tcp            Unit is ready
  cinder-ceph/0*               active    idle            10.113.1.66                         Unit is ready
  cinder-mysql-router/0*       active    idle            10.113.1.66                         Unit is ready
glance/0*                      active    idle   0/lxd/4  10.113.1.62     9292/tcp            Unit is ready
  glance-mysql-router/0*       active    idle            10.113.1.62                         Unit is ready
keystone/0*                    active    idle   0/lxd/3  10.113.1.57     5000/tcp            Unit is ready
  keystone-mysql-router/0*     active    idle            10.113.1.57                         Unit is ready
mysql-innodb-cluster/0         active    idle   0/lxd/0  10.113.1.51                         Unit is ready: Mode: R/O, Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.
mysql-innodb-cluster/1*        active    idle   1/lxd/0  10.113.1.52                         Unit is ready: Mode: R/O, Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.
mysql-innodb-cluster/2         active    idle   2/lxd/0  10.113.1.49                         Unit is ready: Mode: R/W, Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.
neutron-api/0*                 active    idle   1/lxd/2  10.113.1.56     9696/tcp            Unit is ready
  neutron-api-mysql-router/0*  active    idle            10.113.1.56                         Unit is ready
  neutron-api-plugin-ovn/0*    active    idle            10.113.1.56                         Unit is ready
nova-cloud-controller/0*       active    idle   1/lxd/3  10.113.1.59     8774/tcp,8775/tcp   Unit is ready
  ncc-mysql-router/0*          active    idle            10.113.1.59                         Unit is ready
nova-compute/0*                active    idle   0        10.113.1.32                         Unit is ready
  ovn-chassis/2*               active    idle            10.113.1.32                         Unit is ready
nova-compute/1                 active    idle   1        10.113.1.30                         Unit is ready
  ovn-chassis/0                active    idle            10.113.1.30                         Unit is ready
nova-compute/2                 active    idle   2        10.113.1.31                         Unit is ready
  ovn-chassis/1                active    idle            10.113.1.31                         Unit is ready
openstack-dashboard/0*         active    idle   2/lxd/4  10.113.1.61     80/tcp,443/tcp      Unit is ready
  dashboard-mysql-router/0*    active    idle            10.113.1.61                         Unit is ready
ovn-central/0*                 active    idle   0/lxd/2  10.113.1.54     6641/tcp,6642/tcp   Unit is ready
ovn-central/1                  active    idle   1/lxd/1  10.113.1.53     6641/tcp,6642/tcp   Unit is ready (leader: ovnnb_db, ovnsb_db)
ovn-central/2                  active    idle   2/lxd/1  10.113.1.55     6641/tcp,6642/tcp   Unit is ready
placement/0*                   active    idle   2/lxd/3  10.113.1.60     8778/tcp            Unit is ready
  placement-mysql-router/0*    active    idle            10.113.1.60                         Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server/0*             active    idle   2/lxd/2  10.113.1.58     5672/tcp,15672/tcp  Unit is ready
vault/0*                       active    idle   0/lxd/1  10.113.1.50     8200/tcp            Unit is ready (active: true, mlock: disabled)
  vault-mysql-router/0*        active    idle            10.113.1.50                         Unit is ready

Machine  State    DNS          Inst id              Series  AZ       Message
0        started  10.113.1.32  node3                jammy   default  Deployed
0/lxd/0  started  10.113.1.51  juju-25c531-0-lxd-0  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/1  started  10.113.1.50  juju-25c531-0-lxd-1  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/2  started  10.113.1.54  juju-25c531-0-lxd-2  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/3  started  10.113.1.57  juju-25c531-0-lxd-3  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/4  started  10.113.1.62  juju-25c531-0-lxd-4  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/5  started  10.113.1.63  juju-25c531-0-lxd-5  jammy   default  Container started
0/lxd/6  started  10.113.1.67  juju-25c531-0-lxd-6  jammy   default  Container started
1        started  10.113.1.30  node1                jammy   default  Deployed
1/lxd/0  started  10.113.1.52  juju-25c531-1-lxd-0  jammy   default  Container started
1/lxd/1  started  10.113.1.53  juju-25c531-1-lxd-1  jammy   default  Container started
1/lxd/2  started  10.113.1.56  juju-25c531-1-lxd-2  jammy   default  Container started
1/lxd/3  started  10.113.1.59  juju-25c531-1-lxd-3  jammy   default  Container started
1/lxd/4  started  10.113.1.64  juju-25c531-1-lxd-4  jammy   default  Container started
1/lxd/5  started  10.113.1.66  juju-25c531-1-lxd-5  jammy   default  Container started
2        started  10.113.1.31  node2                jammy   default  Deployed
2/lxd/0  started  10.113.1.49  juju-25c531-2-lxd-0  jammy   default  Container started
2/lxd/1  started  10.113.1.55  juju-25c531-2-lxd-1  jammy   default  Container started
2/lxd/2  started  10.113.1.58  juju-25c531-2-lxd-2  jammy   default  Container started
2/lxd/3  started  10.113.1.60  juju-25c531-2-lxd-3  focal   default  Container started
2/lxd/4  started  10.113.1.61  juju-25c531-2-lxd-4  jammy   default  Container started
2/lxd/5  started  10.113.1.65  juju-25c531-2-lxd-5  jammy   default  Container started
```

From the Horizon web ui, I launched a new Ubuntu 22 instance and I am able to ssh into the machine. However, when I go to Instances>{Instance Name}>Console, noVNC seems to load, but it just says "Something went wrong, connection is closed". It does give me the option for show console the console in a new tab, but it still shows the same error. I believe noVNC is loading because it shows the "Send CtrlAltDel" button in the top right corner.

My next step was to check the services running on the nova-cloud-controller charm. This is running as an LXD container at 10.113.1.59 (see juju status log).

```
$ systemctl status nova-novncproxy.service 
● nova-novncproxy.service - OpenStack Compute novncproxy
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nova-novncproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-12 15:32:25 UTC; 11min ago
       Docs: man:nova-novncproxy(1)
   Main PID: 1900710 (nova-novncproxy)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 314572)
     Memory: 99.1M
        CPU: 3.018s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nova-novncproxy.service
             └─1900710 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/nova-novncproxy --config-file=/etc/nova/nova.conf --log-file=/var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log

Jul 12 15:32:25 juju-25c531-1-lxd-3 systemd[1]: Started OpenStack Compute novncproxy.
Jul 12 15:32:25 juju-25c531-1-lxd-3 nova-novncproxy[1900710]: Modules with known eventlet monkey patching issues were imported prior to eventlet monkey patching: urllib3. This warning can usually be ignored if the caller is only importing and not >
Jul 12 15:32:27 juju-25c531-1-lxd-3 nova-novncproxy[1900710]: Deprecated: Option "logdir" from group "DEFAULT" is deprecated. Use option "log-dir" from group "DEFAULT".
```

```
$ cat /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log
2022-07-12 15:32:24.759 1888563 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] In exit
2022-07-12 15:32:27.790 1900710 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] WebSocket server settings:
2022-07-12 15:32:27.791 1900710 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - Listen on 0.0.0.0:6080
2022-07-12 15:32:27.791 1900710 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - Web server (no directory listings). Web root: /usr/share/novnc
2022-07-12 15:32:27.792 1900710 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - SSL/TLS support
2022-07-12 15:32:27.792 1900710 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-]   - proxying from 0.0.0.0:6080 to None:None
2022-07-12 15:32:32.664 1900717 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 172.16.33.2 - - [12/Jul/2022 15:32:32] 172.16.33.2: SSL/TLS (wss://) WebSocket connection
2022-07-12 15:32:32.665 1900717 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 172.16.33.2 - - [12/Jul/2022 15:32:32] 172.16.33.2: Path: '/?token=21fff4d4-5596-4586-95b3-705f9116070b'
2022-07-12 15:32:32.917 1900717 INFO nova.compute.rpcapi [req-2123ff31-79c5-4d43-ab1d-0a85c81c8785 - - - - -] Automatically selected compute RPC version 6.0 from minimum service version 61
2022-07-12 15:32:32.954 1900717 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-2123ff31-79c5-4d43-ab1d-0a85c81c8785 - - - - -]   2: connect info: ConsoleAuthToken(access_url_base='https://10.113.1.59:6080/vnc_auto.html',console_type='novnc',created_at=2022-07-12T15:29:38Z,host='127.0.0.1',id=21,instance_uuid=7446a69f-73e1-4787-ad11-b22be5662e44,internal_access_path=None,port=5900,token='***',updated_at=None)
2022-07-12 15:32:32.955 1900717 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-2123ff31-79c5-4d43-ab1d-0a85c81c8785 - - - - -]   2: connecting to: 127.0.0.1:5900
2022-07-12 15:32:32.955 1900717 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-2123ff31-79c5-4d43-ab1d-0a85c81c8785 - - - - -] handler exception: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2022-07-12 15:40:29.753 1903447 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] handler exception: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] unexpected eof while reading (_ssl.c:997)
2022-07-12 15:40:30.789 1903448 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 172.16.33.2 - - [12/Jul/2022 15:40:30] 172.16.33.2: SSL/TLS (wss://) WebSocket connection
2022-07-12 15:40:30.790 1903448 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [-] 172.16.33.2 - - [12/Jul/2022 15:40:30] 172.16.33.2: Path: '/?token=21fff4d4-5596-4586-95b3-705f9116070b'
2022-07-12 15:40:30.916 1903448 INFO nova.console.websocketproxy [req-85b9a81e-34a4-4679-ade7-f3d68e6f2f40 - - - - -] handler exception: The token '***' is invalid or has expired
```

I restarted the nova-novnc service, but that did not resolve the issue.

I also checked `tcpdump` on the compute nodes where the instance was hosted, but it did not receive any traffic on port 5900. I did the same from within the vm instance.

My best guess is that there is something configured incorrectly with the nova-cloud-controller, but I'm not sure what.

Here is the nova.conf file on the nova-cloud-controller file:

```
$ cat /etc/nova/nova.conf 
# train
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
[DEFAULT]
verbose=False
debug=False
dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
dhcpbridge=/usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge
logdir=/var/log/nova
state_path=/var/lib/nova
iscsi_helper=tgtadm
libvirt_use_virtio_for_bridges=True
connection_type=libvirt
root_helper=sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf
volumes_path=/var/lib/nova/volumes
enabled_apis=osapi_compute,metadata
compute_driver=libvirt.LibvirtDriver
use_ipv6 = False
osapi_compute_listen = 0.0.0.0
metadata_host = 0.0.0.0
s3_listen = 0.0.0.0
enable_new_services = True


transport_url = rabbit://nova:<*redacted*>@10.113.1.58:5672/openstack


osapi_compute_workers = 4

cpu_allocation_ratio = 2
ram_allocation_ratio = 0.98
disk_allocation_ratio = 1

use_syslog=False
my_ip = 10.113.1.59

cert=/etc/apache2/ssl/nova/cert_10.113.1.59
key=/etc/apache2/ssl/nova/key_10.113.1.59



libvirt_vif_driver = nova.virt.libvirt.vif.LibvirtGenericVIFDriver
libvirt_user_virtio_for_bridges =  True
security_group_api = neutron
nova_firewall_driver = nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
default_floating_pool = ext_net
network_api_class = nova.network.neutronv2.api.API
volume_api_class=nova.volume.cinder.API
osapi_compute_listen_port = 8754
metadata_listen_port = 8755


[upgrade_levels]
compute = auto



[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:<*redacted*>@127.0.0.1/nova
max_pool_size = 4


[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:<*redacted*>@127.0.0.1/nova_api
max_pool_size = 4


[glance]
api_servers = https://10.113.1.62:9292

[neutron]
url = https://10.113.1.56:9696
region_name = RegionOne
auth_url = https://10.113.1.57:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = service_domain
user_domain_name = service_domain
project_name = services
username = nova
password = <*redacted*>
# True
service_metadata_proxy = True
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = <*redacted*>


[keystone_authtoken]
auth_type = password
auth_uri = https://10.113.1.57:5000/v3
auth_url = https://10.113.1.57:35357/v3
project_domain_name = service_domain
user_domain_name = service_domain
service_type = compute
project_name = services
username = nova
password = <*redacted*>
signing_dir = /var/cache/nova

memcached_servers = inet6:[::1]:11211


[cinder]

os_region_name = RegionOne

cross_az_attach = True


[osapi_v3]
enabled=True



[conductor]
workers = 4

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]


[oslo_messaging_notifications]
driver = messagingv2
transport_url = rabbit://nova:<*redacted*>@10.113.1.58:5672/openstack

[notifications]
notification_format = unversioned


[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path=/var/lock/nova

[vnc]



[spice]



[serial_console]
enabled = false
base_url = ws://10.113.1.59:6083/



[placement]
auth_url = https://10.113.1.57:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = service_domain
user_domain_name = service_domain
project_name = services
username = nova
password = <*redacted*>
os_region_name = RegionOne
region_name = RegionOne
randomize_allocation_candidates = true

[scheduler]
# NOTE(jamespage): perform automatic host cell mapping
#                  until we can orchestrate this better
#                  using the nova-cc <--> nova-compute
#                  relation
discover_hosts_in_cells_interval = 30

workers = 4



[filter_scheduler]

enabled_filters = AvailabilityZoneFilter,ComputeFilter,ComputeCapabilitiesFilter,ImagePropertiesFilter,ServerGroupAntiAffinityFilter,ServerGroupAffinityFilter,DifferentHostFilter,SameHostFilter



# Disable BuildFailureWeigher as any failed build will result
# in a very low weighting for the hypervisor, resulting in
# instances all being scheduled to hypervisors with no build
# failures.
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-nova-cloud-controller/+bug/1818239
build_failure_weight_multiplier = 0.0


[api]
auth_strategy=keystone
[wsgi]
api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini

[pci]

[oslo_middleware]

# Bug #1758675
enable_proxy_headers_parsing = true


[quota]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your configuration file it makes me suspicious why no configurations are made in the `[vnc]` section.

It should look like this, for example:

```
my_ip = IP_ADDRESS
[vnc]
enabled = True
novncproxy_base_url = http://IP_ADDRESS:6080/vnc_auto.html
server_listen = $my_ip
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
```

- `IP_ADDRESS` being the management IP address of the computer you are running nova-compute on.

**My advice:**

Change your configuration like explained above, restart the nova services and then test via

```
openstack console url show <NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE>
```

which URL is returned and whether you can access this URL using your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As this was a testing cluster, I have since destroyed this setup and had redeployed it with another configuration. I was able to get spice to work, but not noVNC which would be preferable IMO. I'll try that configuration soon to see if I can get it working.